# Trying to get python to search a CSV file for a certain variable, but I want it to be more specific

Tags: python, csv

I am using python to search a CSV file for a certain variable, but I want it to be more specific. What I mean is, is that if I am searching a CSV file for, say, the word "dog". If I input the word "do" into it, as it is part of "dog" it will accept it. How can I change this?

```
a = input("Enter your e-mail: ") 
b = input("Enter your password: ") 

import csv 
c = csv.reader(open('Address Book.csv')) 
for row in c:
     if a in (row[5]): 
          if b in (row[6]): 
               print ("Your details are:") 
               print ("First Name:", row[0])
               print ("Surname:", row[1])
               print ("House Number and Street Name:", row[2])
               print ("Town/City:", row[3])
               print ("Postcode:", row[4])
               print ("E-mail:", row [5])
               print ("Password:", row [6])
          else:
               print ("Password is incorrect")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking that `a` and `b` are in your row fields, you should check if the variables are exactly equal using:

```
for row in c:
     if a == row[5]:
          if b == row[6]:
               print("...")
```

Thus, if you input `a` as `do` and `row[5]` is `dog`, the equality condition would fail and the code won't be executed.